# SQL: SELECT number text base on a number

Tags: sql, select, text, integer

**Background**: I have an SQL database that contain a column (foo) of a `text` type and not `integer`. In the column I store **integer** in a `text` form.

**Question**: Is it possible to `SELECT` the row that contains (in foo column) number greater/lesser than *n*?

**PS**: I have a very good reason to store them as text form. Please refrain from commenting on that.

---

**Update**: (Forgot to mention) I am storing it in SQLite3.

Comment: Which DB type are you storing it in? MS-SQL? IMHO while you may have good reason for storing as text, and I dont doubt you do, sharing that it maybe that the reason you store it in text can be done different and make the query easier.

Comment: @BugFinder Thank you for your concern, I have already gotten the correct answer.

Comment: Thats OK, you had no answers when I posted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT foo
FROM Table
WHERE CAST(foo as int)>@n
```

Comment: @BiggsTRC That's correct, but then that's what you get for poor database design.

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from   tableName
where  cast(textColumn as int) > 5
```

Comment: you are about 20 seconds late from being the correct first responder, sorry for that. I will +1 you for effort and correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple CAST in the WHERE clause will work as long as you are sure that the data in the foo column is going to properly convert to an integer.  If not, your SELECT statement will throw an error.  I would suggest you add an extra step here and take out the non-numeric characters before casting the field to an int.  Here is a link on how to do something similar:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/13/sql-server-udf-function-to-parse-alphanumeric-characters-from-string/

The only real modification you would need to do on this function would be to change the following lines:

```
PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z]%', @string)
```

to

```
PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @string)
```

The results from that UDF should then be castable to an int without it throwing an error.  It will further slow down your query, but it will be safer.  You could even put your CAST inside the UDF and make it one call.  The final UDF would look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UDF_ParseAlphaChars
(
@string VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @IncorrectCharLoc SMALLINT
SET @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @string)
WHILE @IncorrectCharLoc > 0
BEGIN
SET @string = STUFF(@string, @IncorrectCharLoc, 1, '')
SET @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @string)
END
SET @string = @string
RETURN CAST(@string as int)
END
GO
```

Your final SELECT statement would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE UDF_ParseAlphaChars(Foo) > 5
```

**EDIT**

Based upon the new information that the database is SQLite, the above probably won't work directly.  I don't believe SQLite has native support for UDFs.  You might be able to create a type of UDF using your programming language of choice (like this: http://www.christian-etter.de/?p=439)

The other option I see to safely get all of your data (an IsNumeric would exclude certain rows from your results, which might not be what you want) would probably be to create an extra column that has the int representation of the string.  It is a little more dangerous in that you need to keep two fields in sync, but it will allow you to quickly sort and filter the table data.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information. It seems as though my program runs without a glitch when doing `cast` even when certain row contains 'N/A'. So +1 to you but I would have to give the check mark to the first correct responder. Thanks again.

Comment: @Byte - Good to know.  I would be careful, however, with your expectations.  For example, do you want the "n/a" rows to show ever?  If so, do they?  If your filter says "< 5", would that include the "n/a" records or not?  Carefully check to see what happens with these rows and figure out if that is what you are expecting.  Otherwise you may find that your numbers are off.  For example, if you did a count of those ">=5" and another count of those "<5" and added the two numbers together, you might not get the total number of records (which might be right or wrong, depending on your use case)

Comment: Yes I have considered them and Here is what it looks like in my code: `AND (NOT CAST(numberText as int) <= '5' OR numberText = 'N/A')` as to exclude the ones that are below 5 but include those `N/A`. I used these in Objective-C with an iOS app using *libsqlite3.dylib*. It might not work elsewhere, but for this case it does work. But without your answer, I would totally forget about `N/A`, so for that, I thank you.

Comment: @Byte Great.  Glad to hear it works and that you won't be surpised by the results at an inopportune time.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table
    WHERE CAST(foo as int) > 2000
```